# Delete text using file operators in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

Say there is a code:

```
with open("example.pdf", "r") as file:
  String = file.seek(-11, os.SEEK_END)
  print(String)
```

and the output is `Hello Hello`

How would you change the text in the file "example.pdf" so that everything after the first Hello is deleted using file operators(read/write/append)?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: There is the `truncate` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=io#io.IOBase.truncate

Comment: Is example.pdf an Adobe Acrobat PDF file or is it plain text?

Comment: @DarkKnight It is a pdf. But I'm going read as binary, and then convert to string. It is for eof markers, but I'm making the question more generic

Comment: @MichaelButscher I'll definitely look into this. But would you know if I can truncate things if read in binary?

Comment: Sure, `truncate` sees files as byte sequences without caring about data formats like PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file in the appropriate mode. Determine the offset where you want to truncate the file. Call truncate() and close the file.

For example (for a plain text file):

```
import os

def remove_after(filename, text):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        offset = contents.find(text)
        if offset >= 0:
            pos = offset + len(text)
            f.seek(pos, os.SEEK_SET)
            f.truncate()

remove_after('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt', 'hello')
```

For a binary file the mode should be rb+ and the mechanism for determining the truncation point is likely to be different.

Bear in mind though that deleting arbitrary content from a binary file may break its internal structure depending on what the file is